# Rails 3.1 How To Use Parent Attribute When Saving A Child?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Working on a Rails 3.1 project using Devise.

My User model has_many :courses and a Course belongs_to :user.

The User has a boolean attribute miles that the Course model needs to check before saving. I'm trying to use the before_save callback in the Course model like this:

```
# check if user preference is miles, if so convert entered value to kilometers. All 
# distances are stored as kilometers and converted to miles if necessary

before_save :convert_distance 

def convert_distance
    if course.user.miles
       course.distance = course.distance * 1.6
    end
end
```

Obviously I can't use course.user.miles because the new course hasn't had the user_id set yet.

So how can I check the value of the user.miles attribute?  Is this something I need to do in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it depends on how you're creating the `Course` for the `User`. For example, this works in a CoursesController that also knows who the user is:

```
course = user.courses.build(params[:course])
if course.save
  # ...
end
```

Using **[`#build`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)** on an association assigns the appropriate parent id, so the `user` will be visible from the `course`.

Comment: The real problem was using course instead of self. I changed course.user.miles to self.user.mile and it works. But your response removed the blinders - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `after_commit` callback in this case.